# How to log OpenTelemetry data with python logger in an async app?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, open-telemetry

So I've got this Python app. Basically it takes a job request, and runs a task. It is using asyncio so the methods are async/await.
I wanted to create a logging Filter which added some trace context (trace/span IDs along with some attributes) to the log messages.
But what ends up happening is it ends up calling `end()` on an ended span. I've narrowed the code down to demonstrate:

```py
from logging import LogRecord
import uvicorn
import asyncio
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider

tracer = trace.get_tracer("Demo")

provider = TracerProvider()
trace.set_tracer_provider(provider)

class spanFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record: LogRecord) -> LogRecord:
        with trace.get_current_span() as span:
            print("OK!")
        return True

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
task_logger = logging.getLogger("task")
task_logger.addFilter(spanFilter())

class Task:
    
    async def run(self):
        with tracer.start_as_current_span("Run Task") as span:
            task_logger.info("Running task")
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

app = FastAPI()

# Enable instrumentation
FastAPIInstrumentor.instrument_app(app)

@app.post('/job')
async def create_job():
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("Job Request") as span:
        task = Task()
        await task.run()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=7080)
```

The output I get is:

```
OK!
INFO:task:Creating new session
OK!
WARNING:opentelemetry.sdk.trace:Calling end() on an ended span.
WARNING:opentelemetry.sdk.trace:Calling end() on an ended span.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53663 - "POST /job HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```